# Proper use of optional package features and dependencies

Tags: r, dependencies, r-package

I'm trying to provide some *optional*, convenient features to a package `foo` but I struggle with the dependencies of the dependencies.
Specifically, I'd like to use some features from the bioconductor `KEGGgraph`-package *if* it is installed. `KEGGgraph` itself depends on the `graph`-package.
From what I read (although it is not clear) is to include `KEGGgraph` (and `graph`?) as suggested.

From [the documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Suggested-packages) I see that `requireNamespace` is now encouraged together with usage of `::` instead of `require` inside functions. Indeed the package check will also complain if `require` is used. However, when I use `requireNamespace` and `::` the dependencies of `KEGGgraph` is not found.

Consider the following minimal reproducible example.
With `KEGGgraph` installed and a fresh R-session. 
The function below cannot find a function in the `graph`-package:

```
# If KEGGgraph is not installed:
#source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
#biocLite("KEGGgraph")

convenientFunction <- function() {
  if (requireNamespace("KEGGgraph")) {
    tmp.file <- paste0(tempfile(), ".kgml")
    kgml <- KEGGgraph::retrieveKGML("hsa:04115", organism = "hsa",
                                    destfile = tmp.file, method = "internal")
    return(KEGGgraph::parseKGML2DataFrame(tmp.file))
  } else {
    stop("This function needs KEGGgraph and its dependencies")
  }
}

convenientFunction()
#Loading required namespace: KEGGgraph
#trying URL 'http://www.genome.jp/kegg-bin/download?entry=hsa04115&format=kgml'
#Content type 'text/xml' length unknown
#opened URL
#.......... .......... ......
#downloaded 26 KB
#
# Error in nodeDataDefaults(gR, "KEGGNode") <- env.node : 
#  could not find function "nodeDataDefaults<-"
```

It is as-if `requireNamespace` does nothing. The error reproduce by running:

```
# In a new R-session...
requireNamespace("KEGGgraph") # With and without this line
tmp.file <- paste0(tempfile(), ".kgml")
kgml <- KEGGgraph::retrieveKGML("hsa:04115", organism = "hsa",
                                destfile = tmp.file, method = "internal")
KEGGgraph::parseKGML2DataFrame(tmp.file)
```

If `require("KEGGgraph")` has been called it works fine:

```
require("KEGGgraph")
res <- convenientFunction()
```

Is it really necessary for users to `require` this optional package manually?
Adding `&& requireNamespace("graph")` into the `if`-condition in the function definition does not seem to help.

Comment: Shot from the hip:   `rc <- requireNamespace("KEGGgraph", quietly=TRUE, character.only=TRUE)` and then you can test `rc`.   I think I recently fell for that too -- `requireNamespace()` is _not_ a direct replacement for `require()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem with KEGGgraph -- it uses but does not import graph::nodeDataDefaults<-. The solution is to get in touch with `maintainer("KEGGgraph")` and ask them to update their NAMESPACE

```
KEGGgraph$ svn diff
Index: NAMESPACE
===================================================================
--- NAMESPACE   (revision 104133)
+++ NAMESPACE   (working copy)
@@ -2,7 +2,7 @@

 importFrom(XML, "xmlAttrs", "xmlChildren", "xmlName", "xmlRoot", "xmlTreeParse")

-importFrom(graph, "edges", "nodes<-", "nodes", "edgeData")
+importFrom(graph, "edges", "nodes<-", "nodes", "edgeData", "nodeDataDefaults<-")

 exportPattern("^[^\\.]")
 exportMethods("getDisplayName",
```

It seems likely that there are other missing imports, the heavy-handed solution is to simply `import(graph)`; a lighter though imperfect touch is to use [codetoolsBioC](https://hedgehog.fhcrc.org/bioconductor/trunk/madman/Rpacks/codetoolsBioC/)::`writeNamespaceImports()` to generate the imports (this function is buggy so not to be relied on 100%).

A work-around is to say `library(graph)` or `Depends: graph` in your package; this will put graph on the `search()` path, and KEGGgraph will find the missing import there (this is why KEGGgraph itself works -- it Depends: on graph, so missing imports are found on the search path; when you `requireNamespace()`, you don't add KEGGgraph's Depends: packages to the  search path, so `nodeDataDefaults<`- is not found).

Answer (score 3):

I am the maintainer of KEGGgraph. I confirm the problem and has updated the package. In the Bioconductor subversion respository revision 103436, the issue is addressed and hopefully solved.

The solution is almost as Martin suggested, to explicitly import the function from the *graph* package. I took the chance also changed the dependency policy of *KEGGgraph* so that the *graph* package is imported from instead of being dependent on. Hopefully this makes KEGGgraph more friendly to uses cases illustrated above.

Thanks for reporting the issue, and thanks to Martin and Dirk for their answers.